# Is it possible to be "invisible" in a Google Drive document /spreadsheet?

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to be "invisible" in a Google Drive document / spreadsheet ?

Obviously someone would be able to see me if I started typing / adding content, but wondered if its possible to not have my initials shown in the top right corner and not have my name shown in last made edits.

Comment: If you don't edit anything, does it still add you to the "last made edits" list?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible but it the document is shared with anyone with the link you could appear as an "anonymous animal". One way to achieve this is by open the link without being signed in in your account. On Chrome, right click the document link and open it on incognito mode.

## Related

- [Anonymous or unknown people in a file](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just planning to view it (not edit it), right-clicking the doc/sheet/etc. from your Google Drive and selecting "Preview" should work.  It opens a view-only version of the doc.

The main downside of this, to me anyway, is that it opens it right there on that tab, so it's a pain to have more than one view-only option open at a time.

[image: Screenshot of right-click menu]